# ErrorDocument 404 just shows "404"

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have setted up my .htaccess with some bundles of rewrites, although when I go to an invalid directory which the ErrorDocument 404 is already set up, it just shows "404" on the page, nothing else, just a plain text with "404".

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php

ErrorDocument 404 404
```

Why doesn't it show the 404 page, if I go to `404.php` or `http://www.mydomain.com/404` it shows just fine, why won't it show the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reformat your .htaccess, see:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml

The correct line is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
```